# mongoDB is consistent and partitions

Tags: mongodb

According to CAP theorem mongoDB is consistent and partitions. But it is not fall in available category. So How mongodb is not available.

Like traditional databases are consistent and available but not support partitions. So How does mongoDB not comes under availability category?

Comment: Refer this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292215/where-does-mongodb-stand-in-the-cap-theorem

Comment: @notionquest I went through the thread you referred but I have not find how mongoDB is not available?