# Mongodb: availability vs consistency

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

MongoDB follows master-slave architecture. Data is written in master node, which is then replicated to slave nodes. Mongo is said to provide consistency over availability, thinking about which, difference can be explained as:

When master goes down, slave nodes have to decide which one to pick as master which takes time and so system is unavailable for that time window.

Another reason can be: During replication, nodes are locked so that data is copied to all slaves for high consistency, and if we are using slaves for read then locking means unavailability.

But then this can vary as per configuration as Mongo allows to configure role of slaves. We can either have them just for replica purpose(in that case, slave locking may not be required as read requests are only served by master and replication can happen asynchronously) OR we can have slaves for read operations too(in that case, locking may be needed when writes happen so that consistency is there).

So I see there are many variations possible.

So do we have basic rules to define all this?

Comment: `master-slave` terminology is now `Primary-Secondary-...`.

Comment: How you configure the replica-set is as per requirements; your use case of the replica set.

Comment: right....but then how does it impact the CP semantics as guaranteed by Mongo. To me it seems, it can easily move from CP to AP, isn't?

Comment: _"CP semantics as guaranteed by Mongo"_ : can you link to the source?

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/cloud/learn/cap-theorem#toc-mongodb-an-IH4u4oCK

Comment: You can refer MongoDB Manual for information about [Replication  in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB allow you to customize CAP-theorem behaviour depending on your use case requirements , you may adjust  consistency/availability/performance via following settings :

[read-preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/)  possible values:

```
  ["primary","primaryPreferred","secondary","secondaryPreferred","nearest"]
```

[write-concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/write-concern/) possible values:

```
  ["majority",0,1,2,n]
```

[read-concern](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/read-concern/) possible values:

```
  ["local","available","majority","linearizable","snapshot"]
```

[journaling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/journaling/) possible values:

```
  ["true","false"]
```

In addition the question has been discussed  previously in details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11292215/where-does-mongodb-stand-in-the-cap-theorem)